next js routing to specific div element
Suppose I have my "/" page and another page "/Blog". I want to go from /Blog to /#Blogs, which is a route containing the specific element ID. I am trying to do this using the Link component.
here is the code snippet for my Link component:
<Link
href={displayAll ? "/#Blogs" : "/Blog"}
scroll={false}
{displayAll ? "Back Home" : "Read more"}
</Link>

P.s, I successfully navigate to localhost:3000/#Blogs, but I am redirected to the top of the page, rather than the element with id="Blogs"

you can simply use:
href={ "/Blogs"+ "#ID"}

but be careful, its a little more complicated than that. when you navigate between pages, NextJS default behaviour is consider it server component, and if you wrap your page in Suspend component with a fallback, this wont work.
in that case, you have to do it manually, i.e when page loaded, push it to your desired element with UseEffect hook.

thanks a great deal for the detailed explanantion! yeah I think I'll use the useEffect for this, will post my work later
